# Hudson dryRun jobs break after upgrade from 2.2.0 to 2.2.1

Tags: svn, maven, hudson, maven-release-plugin

I just upgraded our Hudson from 2.2.0 to 2.2.1 to fix a known bug with emails. 
Doing this have caused some problems, especially with the dryRun builds.After the upgrade, all the dryRun jobs are failing.

I'm not sure what's happening, but something is causing a svn version conflict:

```
svn: The path '.' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
```

We have several builds to dryRun a release:prepare

```
clean -e release:clean release:prepare -DdryRun=true
```

- Hudson Maven(legacy) plugin -> 2.2.1
- Hudson Maven3 plugin        ->   2.2.0
- Hudson subversion plugin      -> 2.3.2

It seems that the files are downloaded correctly, but the "check for modifications" step seems unnecessary.

Maven output:

```
[INFO] Verifying that there are no local modifications...
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /var/lib/hudson/jobs/anonymousName-app-svn-dryRun-release/workspace/app && svn --non-interactive status
[INFO] Working directory: /var/lib/hudson/jobs/anonymousName-app-svn-dryRun-release/workspace/app
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Unable to check for local modifications
Provider message:
The svn command failed.
Command output:
svn: The path '.' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.BuildFailureException: Unable to check for local modifications
Provider message:
The svn command failed.
Command output:
svn: The path '.' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.

        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:715)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:284)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutorInterceptor.execute(LifecycleExecutorInterceptor.java:65)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at hudson.maven.agent.Main.launch(Main.java:173)
        at hudson.maven.MavenBuilder.call(MavenBuilder.java:164)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$Builder.call(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:917)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$Builder.call(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:848)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:114)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
        at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:283)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:453)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:315)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:150)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:898)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:920)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Unable to check for local modifications
Provider message:
The svn command failed.
Command output:
svn: The path '.' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.

        at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.execute(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:190)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at hudson.maven.agent.PluginManagerInterceptor.executeMojo(PluginManagerInterceptor.java:182)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        ... 28 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jun 14 12:56:15 CEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/63M
```

Comment: Looks like new Hudson checks out your working copy in 1.7 format, but the local client used by Maven is 1.6 . Go to `http://<hudson-server>/configure` -> search for 'Subversion Workspace Version' and see what it says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [version 2.2.1](http://hudson-ci.org/changelog.html), Hudson upgraded to SVNKit 1.7, causing the Subversion working copy to use the non-backwards compatible 1.7 format.

Maven release-plugin calls your SCM provider, Subversion, from the path. You probably have Subversion 1.6 or earlier installed for your command line.

One possible solution is to upgrade your command line Subversion installation to version 1.7.